# jQuery, .removeClass not working

Tags: jquery, delay, addclass, removeclass

I have a simple little function that adds / removes classes from an element based on the scroll position and direction.

Everything was working fine, until I added the delay when adding the `scrolled` class. Now the final `.removeClass('scrolled')` seems to have stopped working.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

This is my code;

```
$(function () {

var position = $(window).scrollTop(),
    $burger = $('.navToggle');

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (  $(document).scrollTop() >= 125 ){

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        $burger.delay(325).queue(function(next){
            $(this).addClass('scrolled');
            next();
        });

        if (scroll > position) {

            $burger.removeClass('going-up up-top').addClass('going-down');
            console.log('moving DOWN the page');

        } else {

            $burger.removeClass('going-down').addClass('going-up');
            console.log('moving UP the page');
        }

        position = scroll;

    } else if ( $(document).scrollTop() == 0 ) {

        $burger.addClass('up-top').removeClass('scrolled');

    }

}); // scroll function

}); // entire function
```

Edit : As requested, I have created a very simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c5d7r0xq/

In the fiddle, the box starts out with a red background. Once the window has scrolled past 125px this changes to green. It should remain green until the window is scrolled to the very top, where it should go back to red. It does briefly switch to red, but then immediately reverts back to green. This is a very simplified example of what I am working on, but follows the same principle.

Comment: What about posting the code in a jsFiddle including the css and html?

Comment: It's not significant, but you're using both `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(document).scrollTop()` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you're `delay`ing the `addClass('scrolled')` until after the `removeClass('scrolled')` has executed. (If I scroll back to the top slowly, the problem doesn't manifest.)

To fix, either queue the `removeClass('scrolled')` as well, or remove the `addClass('scrolled')` delay entirely.

https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/c5d7r0xq/4/

```
    } else if ( $(document).scrollTop() == 0 ) {

        $burger.addClass('up-top').queue(function(next){
            $(this).removeClass('scrolled');
            next();
        });

    }
```

Comment: In your amended fiddle, the background remains green, even when the window is scrolled to the top

Comment: Not after the delay, at least for me.